# Migrate 2TB images from Rackspace to Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We had a requirement to move a 2TB of images from a Rackspace server to an Amazon S3 bucket, to consolidate with other Amazon Web Services (AWS) we were using on a project. Is there any AWS service available to migrate this bunch of files. I am not interested on go with third party CLOUD migration services. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would see 3 different services for your use case

1. S3 Transfer Acceleration

You can use [transfer acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/transfer-files-into-amazon-s3-up-to-300-percent-faster/) it was announced last April. I could not test it (we migrated 1TB of oracle dump files last november)

As mentioned

> It works by carrying HTTP and HTTPS traffic over a highly optimized network bridge that runs between the AWS Edge Location nearest to your clients and your Amazon S3 bucket. There are no gateway servers to manage, no firewalls to open, no special protocols or clients to integrate with, or upfront fees to pay. You simply change the S3 endpoint that your application uses to transfer data, and acceleration is automatically applied. When moving GBs or TBs of data over long distances, it can save hours (or even days) in transfer time

The good thing is that you don't need to change anything in your infrastructure to make it work.

The other good thing is that if AWS finds TA will not improve your upload rate, it will not charge you, from the [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?nc1=h_ls)

> Each time you use Transfer Acceleration to upload an object, we will check whether Transfer Acceleration is likely to be faster than a regular Amazon S3 transfer. If we determine that Transfer Acceleration is not likely to be faster than a regular Amazon S3 transfer of the same object to the same destination AWS region, we will not charge for that use of Transfer Acceleration for that transfer, and may bypass the Transfer Acceleration system for that upload.

2. AWS Direct Connect

Depending where your host servers are located, you could enable [direct connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/?nc1=h_ls)

> AWS Direct Connect makes it easy to establish a dedicated network connection from your premises to AWS. Using AWS Direct Connect, you can establish private connectivity between AWS and your datacenter, office, or colocation environment, which in many cases can reduce your network costs, increase bandwidth throughput, and provide a more consistent network experience than Internet-based connections.

You need to check if the datacenter where your servers are located are part of the list or nearby, if it takes too long to make the connection from your server to a [direct connect location](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/partners/), there will be no benefit

3. snowball

If you have a copy of your files locally or if you can plug the [snowball device](https://aws.amazon.com/importexport/?nc1=h_ls) 
Unless you really have a slow connection from your server, I would not recommend this for 2TB only : it would be faster to upload 2TB of data from backspace to S3 using S3 Transfer Acceleration and most probably more cost effective than shipping the snowball back and forth between AWS and rackspace. snowball are generally used if you have petabytes of data or really run a slow connection

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/send-us-that-data/  shall we try this? Ask rackspace to ship the images in a harddisk to us and then we ship to Amazon. Is this is a efficent way? Please advise

Comment: Import/Export was the ancestor of snowball - before you were able to ship your own hard drive and they will plug it to ec2, download files and resend it to you. It does not exist anymore, it is replaced with snowball. You could ask rackspace if they could accept it so they will receive the AWS snowball plug it on their server, copy the files and resend the AWS. For 2TB I think you can work faster by sending files only

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the term " For 2TB I think you can work faster by sending files only". Could you please explain?

Comment: I mean that it would be faster to upload 2TB of data from backspace to S3 using S3 Transfer Acceleration and most probably more cost effective than shipping the snowball back and forth between AWS and rackspace. snowball are generally used if you have petabytes of data or really run a slow connection