# Transfer 1TB folders & files to AWS S3 from vps web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, scp, s3fs

I need to transfer all our files (With folders structure) to AWS S3. I have researched lot about how this done.

Most of the places mentioned **s3fs**. But looks like this is bit old. And I have tried to install s3fs to my exsisting CentOS 6 web server. But its stuck on **$ make** command. (Yes there is Makefile.in)

And [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452266/migrate-2tb-images-from-rackspace-to-amazon-s3/38453209#38453209) AWS S3 Transfer Acceleration is the next better option. But still I have to write a PHP script (My application is PHP) to transfer all folders and files to S3. It is working same as how file save in S3 (API putObject), but faster. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there any other better solution (I prefer FTP) to transfer 1TB files with folders from CentOS 6 server to AWS S3? Is there any way to use FTP client in EC2 to transfer files from outside CentOS 6 to AWS S3?

Comment: Have you taken a look at s3 sync? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`aws s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

This will preserve your directory structure and can be restarted in case of disconnection. Each execution will only copy new, changed or missing files.

Be aware that 1TB is a lot of data and can take [significant time](https://www.zen.co.uk/smallerbusiness/hosting-and-applications/online-data-backup/data-transfer-times/) to copy.

An alternative is to use [AWS Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/), which is a device that AWS can send to you. It can hold 50TB or 80TB of data. Simply copy your data to the device, then ship it back to AWS and they will copy the data to Amazon S3.

Comment: I came across with s3cmd. I installed s3cmd in my CentOS6 server. Can I use the AWS CLI in same way? Yes Its looks like taking lot of time to copy all the data.

Comment: Yes AWS CLI S3 is the most suitable to do this. Thank you!